# Co-signing using safe-apps-sdk gnosis-safe

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm currently exploring the safe-apps-sdk.

I've created an app that loads inside the gnosis-ui iframe, and connects to the safe-apps-provider. I am able to propose new transactions to the safe co-signers. I also see that fetching queued transactions is an api call to the transaction service so I could show this queue within my dapp.

My question is, is it possible for a co-signer to come into my dapp (inside gnosis ui) and co-sign a queued transaction from within MY dapp (and not have to go to transactions tab on gnosis ui)?

Gnosis ui is connected to a user wallet, but I cannot see if theres a way to trigger the user wallet for a signature from within my dapp and the gnosis provider. I would ideally not have to prompt a metamask connection from within my dapp, but so far this is the only way I've thought of where I could accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `safe-apps-sdk` doesn't have the capabilities to talk to an owner's wallet. You can use regular web3 libraries such as web3.js and ethers.js for that